# Why won't my app start new activity using soundpools?

Tags: onclicklistener, soundpool, forceclose

hi im new to android and i have added a new activity in my app similar to a soundboard each of the 8 key plays a new sound and there are 2 buttons which change the keys to new sounds and the image on each key to new images but it closes everytime i open it, have tried a few fixes but nothing has even got close any and all suggestions welcome here is my code

activity_music.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MusicActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/secondLayout"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/lionkey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/patched"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/lionhead"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/dogkey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/patched2"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/doghead"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/catkey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/patched3"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cathead"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/duckkey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/patched"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/duckhead"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:src="@drawable/monkeykey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/patched2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/monkeyhead"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:background="@drawable/patched3"
    android:src="@drawable/sheepkey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sheephead"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@drawable/pigkey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/patched"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/pighead"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:src="@drawable/elephantkey"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/patched2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/elephanthead"/>

</LinearLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Button1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my java

Music Activity java

```
package com.martinsapp.socialstories;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MusicActivity extends Activity {
SoundPool sp;
int instrument=1;
int lionSound=0;
int dogsound=0;
int catsound =0;
int ducksound =0;
int monkeysound =0;
int sheepsound=0;
int pigsound=0;
int elephantsound=0;
int lettera=0;
int letterc=0;
int letterd=0;
int letterg=0;
int letterk=0;
int lettero=0;
int lettert=0;
int letterw=0;
ImageButton btn1;
ImageButton btn2;
ImageButton btn3;
ImageButton btn4;
ImageButton btn5;
ImageButton btn6;
ImageButton btn7;
ImageButton btn8;
Button button1;
Button button2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);

    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);

    dogsound = sp.load(this, R.raw.puppy_dog,1);
    catsound = sp.load(this, R.raw.kittenmeow,1);
    sheepsound = sp.load(this, R.raw.sheep,1);
    ducksound = sp.load(this, R.raw.quack_quack,1);
    pigsound = sp.load(this, R.raw.pig_snort,1);
    monkeysound = sp.load(this, R.raw.monkey_noise,1);
    lionSound = sp.load(this, R.raw.lion_roar,1);
    elephantsound = sp.load(this, R.raw.lion_roar,1);

    lettera = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_a,1);
    letterc = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_c,1);
    letterd = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_d,1);
    letterg = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_g,1);
    letterk = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_k,1);
    lettero = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_o,1);
    lettert = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_t,1);
    letterw = sp.load(this, R.raw.letter_w,1);

     btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
     btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
     btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
     btn4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
     btn5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
     btn6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
     btn7 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
     btn8 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
    btn8.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);


    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);


    if (instrument == 1){
        btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lionkey);
        btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dogkey);
        btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.catkey);
        btn4.setImageResource(R.drawable.duckkey);
        btn5.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkeykey);
        btn6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sheepkey);
        btn7.setImageResource(R.drawable.pigkey);
        btn8.setImageResource(R.drawable.elephantkey);
    }

}
private OnClickListener ButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton:
                if (instrument == 1){
                    if (lionSound != 0){
                        sp.play(lionSound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                 if (instrument == 2){
                    if (lettera != 0){
                        sp.play(lettera, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                break;

            case R.id.imageButton2:
                if (instrument == 1){
                    if (dogsound != 0){
                        sp.play(dogsound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}

                if (instrument == 2){
                    if (letterc != 0){
                        sp.play(letterc, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                break;

            case R.id.imageButton3:
                if (instrument == 1){
                    if (catsound != 0){
                        sp.play(catsound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                if (instrument == 2){
                    if (letterd != 0){
                        sp.play(letterd, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                    break;
                    case R.id.imageButton4:
                        if (instrument == 1){
                            if (ducksound != 0){
                                sp.play(ducksound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                        if (instrument == 2){
                            if (letterg != 0){
                                sp.play(letterg, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                        break;
            case R.id.imageButton5:
                if (instrument == 1){
                    if (monkeysound != 0){
                        sp.play(monkeysound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                if (instrument == 2){
                    if (letterk != 0){
                        sp.play(letterk, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}

                break;
            case R.id.imageButton6:
                if (instrument == 1){
                    if (sheepsound != 0){
                        sp.play(sheepsound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                if (instrument == 2){
                    if (lettero != 0){
                        sp.play(lettero, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton7:
                if (instrument == 1){
                    if (pigsound != 0){
                        sp.play(pigsound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                if (instrument == 2){
                    if (lettert != 0){
                        sp.play(lettert, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton8:
                if (instrument == 1){
                    if (elephantsound != 0){
                        sp.play(elephantsound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                if (instrument == 2){
                    if (letterw != 0){
                        sp.play(letterw, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}}
                break;




            case R.id.Button1:
                instrument = 1;
                if (instrument == 1){
                    btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lionkey);
                    btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dogkey);
                    btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.catkey);
                    btn4.setImageResource(R.drawable.duckkey);
                    btn5.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkeykey);
                    btn6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sheepkey);
                    btn7.setImageResource(R.drawable.pigkey);
                    btn8.setImageResource(R.drawable.elephantkey);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.Button2:
                instrument = 2;
                if (instrument == 2){
                    btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_a);
                    btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_c);
                    btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
                    btn4.setImageResource(R.drawable.g);
                    btn5.setImageResource(R.drawable.k);
                    btn6.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                    btn7.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_t);
                    btn8.setImageResource(R.drawable.w);

                }
        }
    }
};
}
```

and here is the logcat for when the app closes

```
02-01 11:11:42.300  22216-22216/com.martinsapp.socialstories E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL     

EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
                      ComponentInfo{com.martinsapp.socialstories/
com.martinsapp.socialstories.
MusicActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
               (ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.martinsapp.socialstories.MusicActivity.onCreate(MusicActivity.java:86)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:22
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
          (ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad no one answered this as it was my own stupidity button = findviewbyid R.Id.button1 should be R.Id.Button1 It now works